# how to disable printscreen key on windows using python

Tags: python, windows, screenshot, printscreen

Is there any way to disable the print screen key when running a python application?

Maybe editing the windows registry is the way?

Thanks!

Comment: you may be able to make or use an existing global keyboard hook and then listen for the print screen call and not pass it on down the chain, but i have no idea if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

1. printscreen is **OS Functionality**.
2. Their is **No ASCII code** for PrintScreen.
3. Even their are many ways to take PrintScreen.

Thus, You can Disable keyboard but its difficult to stop user from taking PrintScreen.